# Run a powershell script with different credentials

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to run a powershell script to search for a network drive for a certain file. In my testing, I've found that my script works perfectly fine, however the network drive I need to search require my Domain Admin logon.

I have

`Start-Process powershell.exe -Credential "domain\adminusername" -NoNewWindow -ArgumentList "Start-Process powershell.exe -Verb runAs"`

as the very first line of my script, but whenever I run the script I get this error:

```
Start-Process : This command cannot be run due to the error: The directory 
name is invalid.
At Path\to\script.ps1:1 char:1
+ Start-Process powershell.exe -Credential "domain\adminusername" -NoN ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Start-Process], 
InvalidOperationException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : 
InvalidOperationException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartProcessCommand
```

What directory name is it talking about? If I move the script to the actual network drive, I still get the same error. How do you run a script as a different user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `net use` command to gain access or the `new-psdrive` command instead. Another option would be to `start-process` a cmd prompt and use `runas` within it. Also, you may need to include the full path of powershell.exe or add it to the path variable. `%SystemRoot%\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe`

Comment: I have used `New-PSDrive` to map network drives with my admin credentials many times. Or you could always just do a Run As Different User on PowerShell when you first launch it.